# umlaut (ä, ö, ü) german character replacing with ? in Pentaho ETL tool

Tags: database, db2, etl, pentaho

We are processing the data from CSV file to database (DB2) by using pentaho ETL tool.
In the file we are having umlaut (ä, ö, ü) german character, while loading the data from CSV to DB2 ,
the umlaut (ä, ö, ü) chatactes are replaced with ? (question mark) in DB2.

We are not sure why umlaut characters becoming ?, Can you please help on this.

ETL tool : Pentaho (3.0.4)
Database : DB2

Thanks in advance,
Krishna.

We have checked in the database level and we are not sure how to check the process of umlaut characters behaviour in Pentaho ETL tool,

Need to know how Petaho tool deals with Umlaut chatacters and where we need to change.

Comment: It's probably due to having different code pages configured at different points of your pipeline (i.e. your csv file is using something like UTF-8 but Pentaho and/or DB2 is using something like Latin1)

Comment: Check your CSV file input step and see how this values are handled using *Preview*, if characters are not correct try other values for *File encoding*. Else tell which platform DB2 runs on.

Answer (score 1):

In Pentaho, **CSV file input** step has the option to set the encoding of the files. You can set it to UTF-8 (default) or UTF-16 to enable reading special characters like the German umlaut. It seems that the DB2 database is not created with the correct encoding. May be recreating the DB2 database with the right encoding will help in here.

Also, if you are using Pentaho version 3.0.4, I would strongly suggest you upgrading to version 9.x.x as any version prior to 8.x.x are not supported by Hitachi / Pentaho.

[image]

**Sample Loading of German Umlaut words using Pentaho**:

[image]

Comment: agreed, might want to something like notepad++ to determine characterset (or at least make an educated guess)